# React:create Select All/UnSelect All checkboxes on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying data in the checkboxlist. How to implement Select All and UnselectAll buttons that selects all or unselect all checkboxes.

Please find my react code and data coming from api in the sandbox below: https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-pond-07qnue

```
[ {"templateID":"11","templateName":"All” }, {"templateID":"21","templateName":"SC" }]
```

thanks

Comment: The fetch call is unnecessary here, you are just doing a fetch over static array ... please have the accurate data (a dummy data resembling the original)

Comment: fetch API is returning JSon . Trying to assign below JSon  in variable data.                                                                                       
      [ {"templateID":"11","templateName":"All” }, 
        {"templateID":"21","templateName":"SC" }]

Comment: maybe edit your sandbox to render the data correctly and ask for the expected results

Comment: Please edit my sandbox. I am not sure how to hardcode the fetch results with           [ {"templateID":"11","templateName":"All” }, {"templateID":"21","templateName":"SC" }]

Answer (score 0):

First, fetch the data, then create an array:-

```
const getData = () => {
 let LIBID = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).libid;
 let url = `${checkWindowName}/getmanualout?LibraryId=${LIBID}`;

 fetch(url, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Accepts: "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
})
  .then((result) => {
    result.json().then((resp) => {
      console.log("result 1:- ", resp.data);
      if (resp.response === "Success") {
        let dt = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < resp.data.length; i++) {
          dt.push({
            type: resp.data[i].type,
            uniqueid: resp.data[i].uniqueid,
            checkbox: false, // -------create here-------
            id: i,
          });
        }

        setPosts(dt);
        setloader(false);
        setexcelbutton(false);

        console.log("data :- ", dt);
                 
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(() => {
    
  });
};
```

second, I print the data :-

```
<table className="table table-hover" id="table-to-xls">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th >
            <input type="checkbox" onClick={() => allCheckTrue(allTrue)}/>
          </th>
          <th>Unique ID</th>
          <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      {posts.map((item, i) => {
        return (
          <React.Fragment key={i}>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th onClick={() => checkBoxTrueSinghle(item)}>
                  <input type="checkbox"  checked={item.checkBox}></input>
                </th>

                <td className="sz-arg-tb wd-11 pr-2">
                  <p>{item.uniqueid}</p>
                </td>
         
                <td className="sz-arg-tb wd-11 ">
                  <p>{item.type}</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      })}
    </table>
```

third, create function :-

```
//All checkbox true
const allCheckTrue = (allTrue) => {
console.log("all true :- ", allTrue);

let data = posts;

let dt = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (allTrue === true) {
    dt.push({
      type: data[i].type,
      uniqueid: data[i].uniqueid,
      checkBox: false,
      id: i,
    });

    setAllTrue(false);
  } else {
    dt.push({
      type: data[i].type,
      uniqueid: data[i].uniqueid,
      checkBox: true,
      id: i,
    });

    setAllTrue(true);
  }

  setPosts(dt);

  console.log("check :- ", dt);
}
};
```

for single checkout true :-

```
 const singleCheckBox = (item) => {
console.log("item true :- ", item);

var check = posts.findIndex((el) => el.id === item.id);
const checkbox_true = [...posts];

console.log(checkbox_true[check].checkBox);

if (checkbox_true[check].checkBox === true) {
  checkbox_true[check].checkBox = false;
  setPosts(checkbox_true);
} else {
  checkbox_true[check].checkBox = true;
  setPosts(checkbox_true);
}

console.log("check :- ", checkbox_true);
};
```

Comment: Please update my sandbox. It will be of great help if you use my code to fix the issue. My fetch api is returning data [ {"templateID":"11","templateName":"All” }, {"templateID":"21","templateName":"SC" }]